# Crossing Orbits

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a question here that I am stumped with.

The path of an orbit of a planet around a distant sun is $2K^2 + 2I^2 = 50$. The planet orbits the sun at roughly $900$ million kilometers.

The path of an asteroid is $2K - 4I = 8$.

The sun is at point $(0,0)$.  A large clump of rock orbits the star at $6K^2 + 20I^2 =300$.

If the planet, asteroid and clump of rock are on the same plane, what distance from the sun will the asteroid cross the path of the planet and the clump of rock

Comment: As an aside, the clump of rock is in violation of [Kepler's first law of planetary motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion#First_Law); the ellipse described doesn't have a focus at the sun. *For shame!* :-P